# How to make this query MySQL 5.7 compatible without altering "sql_mode=only_full_group_by"?

Tags: mysql

I have a rather crazy SQL-Query which works perfectly in an MySQL < 5.7 environment:

```
SELECT
    sp.id,
    (SELECT COUNT(spa.id) FROM project_attribute AS spa WHERE spa.project = sp.id AND spa.attribute = pa.attribute AND spa.attribute_value = pa.attribute_value) * 25
    +
    (SELECT COUNT(spt.id) FROM project_task AS spt WHERE spt.project = sp.id AND spt.address = pt.address) * 10
    +
    (SELECT COUNT(spc.id) FROM project_campaign AS spc WHERE spc.project = sp.id AND spc.campaign = pc.campaign) * 500
    +
    (SELECT COUNT(sp2.id) FROM project AS sp2 WHERE sp2.id = sp.id AND sp2.category = p.category) * 10
    +
    (SELECT COUNT(sp3.id) FROM project AS sp3 WHERE sp3.id = sp.id AND sp3.special_category = p.special_category) * 25
    AS
    similarity
FROM
    project AS p
LEFT JOIN project_attribute AS pa ON(p.id = pa.project)
LEFT JOIN project_task AS pt ON(p.id = pt.project)
LEFT JOIN project_campaign AS pc ON(p.id = pc.project)
LEFT JOIN project AS sp ON(p.id != sp.id)
WHERE
    p.id = :id
AND
    sp.is_live = TRUE
GROUP BY
    sp.id
ORDER BY
    similarity DESC,
    sp.created DESC
LIMIT 6
```

Basically this is an algorithm to select the 6 most similar projects to a given ID, based on multiple related tables.

Unfortunately, when running this in an > 5.7 environment, I get the following error:

```
Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'database.pa.attribute' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

If I add "similarity" to GROUP BY, it doesn't throw an error, but delivers wrong results (e.g. first and fourth result are the same entry).

I also tried adding "SELECT DISTINCT sp.id" but it still has the same project twice in the result.

**Is it possible to achieve the same results as before, without changing "sql_mode=only_full_group_by"?**

Comment: @DanFromGermany do subselects work inside SUM()? I tried it but it gives me a syntax error. However, the main issue is that I need "similarity" in GROUP BY, which delivers different results if I do so.

Comment: Why do you even use subselects when you already join the appropriate tables? I rather do a triple join on the same table before doing a single subquery.

Comment: @DanFromGermany actually, the subselects are different from the joins. I am comparing "projects (p*)" to "similar projects (sp*)". e.g.: "spa.attribute = pa.attribute". I know it's confusing, but as I said it works fine in an older MySQL environment.

Comment: Even when that GROUP BY was allowed, it was probably giving you garbage results (if `p` is 1:N with any of `pa`, `pt`, or `pc`); there reason you're getting the same project multiple times is the GROUP BY was hiding the other result (not summing them).

Comment: @DanFromGermany what sql dialect has SUM that takes multiple arguments?

Comment: Certainly MySQL's `SUM()` does not take multiple expressions. I also checked doc for Microsoft SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL, and SQLite. None of them take multiple arguments.

Comment: @sbo I think your query can be fixed with `GROUP BY sp.id, similarity` but I have not created a test for this.